# Using ggplot2 with Rshiny: Incorrect levels displayed on ggplot y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

When I use ggplot2 in RShiny like so:

```
# Define UI for miles per gallon application
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  # Application title
  headerPanel("Healthcare"),

  # Sidebar with controls to select the variable to plot against mpg
  # and to specify whether outliers should be included
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("variable", "Factor: ",
                list("Uninsured %" = "uninsured", 
                     "Primary Care Physicians" = "primary_care_physicians", 
                     "Mental Health Providers" = "mental_health_providers",
                     "Dentists" = "dentists"
                     ))
  ),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("yearPlot"))
))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

      output$yearPlot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(insurance, aes(year, input$variable, color = County)) + geom_point() + geom_line() 
      })

    })
```

My output is like so:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

I don't know what the problem is because the numeric variables should be defined according to my dataset. But somehow my variable is reduced to just one point on the graph in the y-axis.

Comment: Use `aes_string()` with character values like `input$variable`. You'd want to use it for your other aesthetics as well: `aes("year", input$variable, color = "County")`

Comment: When I do that, I get this error: `default method not implemented for type 'list'`

Comment: Okay I found my mistake. Thanks a lot for your help!